# How to add a Label and Combo Box to the ToolBar in QT Designer?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

So, I know that QToolBar also accepts widgets like a QLabel through the method QToolBar::addWidget, but I'd like to know how this is possible to do in QT Designer. I've tried to do this, but nothing seems to work in QT Designer.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible using the standard widgets. You can only drag and drop actions from the Action Editor onto a toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Is very simple, see this example with addAction and addWidget.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.status = QStatusBar()
    self.setStatusBar(self.status)
    my_toolbar = QToolBar("toolbar")
    my_toolbar.setIconSize(QSize(48, 48))
    self.addToolBar(my_toolbar)
    my_label = QLabel()
    my_label.setText("Hello World")

    one_action = QAction(QIcon(), "Action one", self)        
    one_action.setStatusTip("Action one on toolbar")
    one_action.triggered.connect(self.action_one)
    my_toolbar.addAction(one_action)

    my_toolbar.addWidget(my_label)
    self.setWindowTitle("Window PyQt5 - 001")
    self.show()
```

Similar for ComboBox start with:

```
selector = QComboBox()
selector.addItems
.addWidget(selector)
```